# Circular progress show more than 100%

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I made a circular chart like in this article:
https://medium.com/@pppped/how-to-code-a-responsive-circular-percentage-chart-with-svg-and-css-3632f8cd7705

However, I also try to show values ​​above 100% on it (the graph shows a comparison of consumption in the current month to the previous one and some times it needs to look like that). I tried to add another circle and opacity to the first one, but it doesn't look good.

I wish it looked liked this:

[image]

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart cons">
  <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />
  <path class="circle-round" stroke-dasharray="100 100" 
        style="opacity: 0.9;" d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0" />
  <path class="circle-round" stroke-dasharray="19 100" d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0" />

  <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage cons-fill">119%</text>
</svg>
```

```
.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 3.8;
}
.circle-round{
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.8;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress 1s ease-out forwards;
}
.circular-chart.cons .circle-round {
  stroke: $cons;
}
@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
}
.cons-fill {
  fill: $cons;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jakub welcome to stackoverflow :) It's necessary to include *your* code relevant to your question so we know how to help you. You can review what's expected of a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Additionally, please limit your scope to 1 question per post. And just for me, can you elaborate what you mean by more than 100%?

Comment: Hi soulshined, sorry for that. I've added code and deleted second question.

Comment: Ok, looks great. I wasn't sure if you were talking about the text or if you wanted like a repeating loader or something (where it just loops infinitely). I tried looking and didn't see a duplicate question so if someone hasn't snagged this by Saturday, I'll try to answer. So just to clarify, you are *not* looking for an infinite loop style loader [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230148/create-svg-progress-circle) which is effectively the same thing? You want a layered progress meter? No JavaScript?

Comment: No infinite loop style loader. It's just static comparsion of two values showed in %. If JS will be necessary, I am open to suggestions. I think now about adding a small line with a shadow in the and if value is above 100% but so far I failed to do it. Thank you for your interest in the topic.

Comment: Frankly a *circular* progress item is not appropriate here. They aren't intended for values above 100%. A bar chart would be a better option.

Comment: @Jakubbb1337 I'm going to edit your question title that better reflects the content. This will help with SEO buzzwords. You should accept one of the answers by clicking the checkmark next to one, if they helped you

Answer (score 4):

Consider a solution - using two animations on different circles.

The start of both animations begins after clicking on the svg canvas `begin="svg1.click"`
First, the first animation works  `id="an_red"`, painting a circle in red in one second `dur="1s"`.

After a full turn of the first animation `id="an_red"`, the second animation `id="an_green"` is turned on, which paints the entire green circle for 10 cycles of the red circle fill animation.

*Please read the comments below in the code.*

```css
.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 3.8;
}
.circle-red{
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.8;
  stroke-linecap: round; 
  stroke:red;
  stroke-dasharray:0 100;
}
.circle-green{
  fill:none;
  stroke: yellowgreen;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray:0 100;   
}

#txt1 {
text-anchor:middle;
dominant-baseline:central;
font-size:6px;
fill:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="80vw" height="80vh" viewBox="0 0 36 36" opacity="1" class="circular-chart cons">
<g id="gr1">  
  <!-- Gray circle  -->
   <path  class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />
  
   
   <path class="circle-red"    
        style="opacity: 0.5;" d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0" >
    <!-- Red circle rotation animation    -->
   <animate
   id="an_red"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   dur="1s"
   values="0 100;100 0"
   begin="svg1.click"
   end="an_green.end-1s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   
   restart="whenNotActive" />
  </path>      
 <circle class="circle-green"   
        cx="17.8155" cy="17.8155" r="14" >
  <!-- Green circle rotation animation -->
      <animate
     id="an_green"
  attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
  begin="svg1.click+1s"
  dur="10s"
  values="0 100; 100 0"
  repeatCount="1"
  
  restart="whenNotActive"/>
    </circle> 
   <text id="txt1" x="50%" y="50%"  >Click me
      <!-- Text fade animation -->
 <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="svg1.click" dur="1s" to="0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
   </text>  
 </g>   
     <animate xlink:href="#svg1" attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" begin="an_green.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
</svg>
```

### Update

Consider the option when circles are located one above the other

The bottom circle is responsible for the animation showing the fill 100%
The upper circle of a brighter color is responsible for filling the remaining 19%.

The animation of this circle begins when the animation of the first, lower circle ends

```
  <!-- Animation filling a dark red circle by 19% -->
    <animate 
     id="an_dark_red"
     attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
     begin="an_red.end"
     dur="1s"
     values="0 100;19 81"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive"  />
```

```css
.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
.circle-round{
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3;
  
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray:0 100; 
  }
 #txt1 {
text-anchor:middle;
dominant-baseline:central;
font-size:8px;
fill:red;
opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" height="80vh" viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart cons" >
   <!-- gray circle background -->
  <path class="circle-bg"  class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

 <path id="red" class="circle-round" stroke="#FFB5B5"
      
         d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0" > 
 
 <!-- Animation filling the red circle 100% -->
 <animate
   id="an_red"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   begin="svg1.click"
   dur="4s"
   values="0 100;100 0"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
   restart="whenNotActive"/>
   </path>  
   
  <path id="dark_red"  class="circle-round"  stroke="red" 
        stroke-dasharray="0 100" 
        d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0" >
   
   <!-- Animation filling a dark red circle by 19% -->
 <animate 
  id="an_dark_red"
  attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
  begin="an_red.end"
  dur="1s"
  values="0 100;19 81"
  fill="freeze"
  restart="whenNotActive"  />
  </path> 
   
    <text id="txt1" x="50%" y="50%"  >119%
      <!-- The appearance of the text -->
 <animate attributeName="opacity" begin="an_dark_red.end" dur="1s" to="1" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
   </text>  
 
</svg>
```

### option with CSS animation of progress equal to 119%

```css
#svg1 {
 opacity:1;
 height:90vh;
 animation: hide 1s ease-out 7s forwards;
 } 
 
 @keyframes hide {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
} 
 .circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
.circle-round{
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray:0 100; 
  } 
  
  #red {
  animation: progress 4s ease-out forwards;
  }
  
  @keyframes progress {
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 0;
  }
} 

#dark_red {
animation: progress2 1s ease-out 3.9s forwards;
}  

@keyframes progress2 {
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 19 81;
  }
} 
  
 #txt1 {
text-anchor:middle;
dominant-baseline:central;
font-size:8px;
fill:red;
opacity:0; 
animation: text_an 2s ease-out 5.1s forwards;
}   

@keyframes text_an {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" height="30vh" viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart cons" >
   <!-- gray circle background -->
  <path class="circle-bg"  class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

 <path id="red" class="circle-round" stroke="#FFB5B5"
      
         d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0" > 
  
   </path>  
   
  <path id="dark_red"  class="circle-round"  stroke="red" 
        stroke-dasharray="0 100" 
        d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0" >
    
  </path> 
   
    <text id="txt1" x="50%" y="50%"  >119%  </text>   
      
 
</svg>
```

**option with CSS animation of progress equal to 175%**

```css
#svg1 {
 opacity:1;
 animation: hide 3s ease-out 10s forwards;
 } 
 
 @keyframes hide {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
} 
 .circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
.circle-round{
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray:0 100; 
  } 
  
  #red {
  animation: progress 4s ease-out forwards;
  }
  
  @keyframes progress {
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 0;
  }
} 

#dark_red {
animation: progress2 3s ease-out 3.9s forwards;
}  

@keyframes progress2 {
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 75 25;
  }
} 
  
 #txt1 {
text-anchor:middle;
dominant-baseline:central;
font-size:8px;
fill:#CB5CCB;
opacity:0; 
animation: text_an 2s ease-out 7s forwards;
}   

@keyframes text_an {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" height="80vh" viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart cons" >
   <!-- gray circle background -->
  <path class="circle-bg"  class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />

 <path id="red" class="circle-round" stroke="#CBAACB"
      
         d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0" > 
  
   </path>  
   
  <path id="dark_red"  class="circle-round"  stroke="#CB5CCB" 
        stroke-dasharray="0 100" 
        d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0" >
    
  </path> 
   
    <text id="txt1" x="50%" y="50%"  >175%  </text>   
      
 
</svg>
```

**Note**

CSS animation option works in all modern browsers including Edge

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. Very nice. [Look smil works](https://caniuse.com/#search=smil) everywhere except `Edge`, `IE`

Comment: I should add it works for the new edge (with chromium), but it's in beta still. I like this a lot in terms of UIX

Comment: @soulshined Added examples of CSS animation. work in all modern browsers, including Edge

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you cannot go further than a full circle unless you extend the path. I agree that this is not the best tool to show these values, but you can do something like this:

```css
:root{
  --cons: #00ff00;
  --atime: 1s;
}
.shade{
  fill: none;
  stroke: #002200;
  stroke-width: 2.8;
  /*stroke-linecap: round;*/
  animation: sprogress var(--atime) ease-out forwards;
}
.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 3.8;
}
.circle-round{
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2.8;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  animation: progress var(--atime) ease-out forwards;
}
.circular-chart.cons .circle-round {
  stroke: var(--cons);
}
@keyframes sprogress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 0 4 146;
  }
}
@keyframes progress {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 150;
  }
}
.cons-fill {
  fill: var(--cons);
  font-size: 30%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart cons" height="100vh">
  <path class="circle-bg" d="M18 2.0845
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831" />
  <path class="circle-round" stroke-dasharray="119 31" d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0 " />
  <path class="shade" stroke-dasharray="0 115 4 31" 
        style="opacity: 0.9;" d="M33.9155 18
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 31.831 0
        a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 -31.831 0                         " />

  <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage cons-fill">119%</text>
</svg>
```

The idea is that the path now has 150 units. To mark where the path is, you have a path with the class `shade`. If you need more than 150, add more `a` elements that keep on turning, and then calculate which values of `stroke-dasharray` you need.

By the way, if you uncomment the `stroke-linecap` in the `shade` class, you will get a funny effect, as *both* ends will be displayed, independently of `stroke-dasharray`.

**EDIT** after comment:

First, it is important to notice that the trick in the original code is that the perimeter of the circumpherence is 100. Therefore, each arc has 50 units. Regarding the [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) property, you can give it pairs of dash-gap values. If the sum of those values is equal to the perimeter of the arc, you can easily control the position and length of the dash. In the case of the `shade` path, you animate from `0 0 4 146` (no dash, no gap, 4 units dash, 146 units gap) to `0 115 4 31` (no dash, 115 units gap, 4 units dash, 31 units gap). This way, the dash always has 4 units, and the end is at `115 + 4 = 119` units. This is not perfect, as the starting value (the end of the dash) is not 0, but 4. The effect is hardly noticeable, but it can be fixed in two ways:

- Mark the percentage with the start of the dash (`0 0 4 146` to `0 119 4 27`).
- Extend the `shade` path at the beginning, then change the `stroke-dasharray` values. For instance, if you add another arc at the beginning the perimeter would be 200, and the values would go from `0 46 4 150` to `0 165 4 31`.

Comment: (+) Probably it is necessary to explain in more detail how several pairs of attribute values work.- ``stroke-dasharray: 0 0 4 146`

Comment: I added an explanation of the strategy to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. It is clear to me that the visible sector remains of constant length `4`    changed the gap in front of and after it  in process of animation  we rotate the sector .